# Two way binding using Silverlight and WCF Service

Tags: c#, silverlight

To simplify the question, I have a single textbox control which I want to apply two way binding. I have an object class named Customer for example on the server side, the silverlight application is obviously a separate project.

```
public class Customer
{
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

In the WCF Service I have query which populates the customer name, and returns a list of type Customer.

```
List<Customer> data = new List<Customer>();
```

On the client side I then have this bound to the textbox control:

```
<TextBox Canvas.Left="345" Canvas.Top="12" Height="23" Name="tb_customer" Width="120" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />

List<ServiceReference.Customer> data = e.Result;
tb_customer.DataContext = data[0];
```

This is working fine, and is binding the customer name to the textbox control. But my question is, when I change the value on the client side how do I go about sending the modified customer name back to the data source, in this case a table named customers in sqlserver. Would I need to implement INotifiyPropertyChanged on the customer class? But obviously the customer class is sitting on the server side, so do I need to create a local instance of the customer class on the client side, and upload these changes via the wcf service back to the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the Textbox up like this:

```
<TextBox Canvas.Left="345" Canvas.Top="12" Height="23" Name="tb_customer" Width="120" Text="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

With this setup, changes made to the value of the textbox will automatically update the state of the *object*, locally.  You will then have to commit the changes back to the datastore.  If you are using an ORM such as Entity Framework, that's easy- just call `SubmitChanges()` on your context and you're done.  If you're not using an ORM, you'll have to handle the update manually.

Comment: If im not using an ORM, what is the best way to handle the update to the wcf service manually?

Comment: You'd have to send the object back to your service (I assume you're using a RIA service) and manually compose and execute an update query.